# Can't Connect to Twitch IRC Server, problem with IP address, C language

Tags: c, chatbot, twitch

I'm trying to build a ChatBot for Twitch entirely in C Language. But i'm having problems in connecting to the server: `irc.chat.twitch.tv` with port `6667`. I'm calling `gethostbyname()` to retrieve the ip address of the hostname, but the connect function never establish the connection, and returns "Connection Failed".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include "Authentication.h"
#include "MessageHandlers.h"


int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct hostent * addr_info;
    char * ip;
    addr_info = gethostbyname("irc.chat.twitch.tv");

    ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)addr_info->h_name);
    printf("%s", ip);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(6667);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nSocket Creation Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nConnecting to Twitch IRC Server...\n");
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nConnection Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   // SendAuthentication(sock);
/*
    while(1)
    {
     OnMessageEvents(sock);
    }
  */  

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong? The twitch resolved ip address seems to be `105.114.99.45`. I searched on Google for the actual ip address, but i didn't find any answers.

I used `nslookup irc.chat.twitch.tv` and tried all the ip addresses, but still i got "Connection Failed".

If i use `telnet irc.chat.twitch.tv 6667` i get a connection and i can perform the login.

Comment: Don't search on Google for DNS results. Use your command like tools like `nslookup` or `dig`. From there verify independently you can connect to that service with something like `telnet irc.chat.twitch.tv 6667`.

Comment: i tried connecting with telnet and it worked fine, i then used the ip address that telnet provided but still the connect function returns "Connection Refused"...

Comment: I don't know where you got that IP from because it's not what `irc.chat.twitch.tv` resolves to right now. They're using Amazon AWS, apparently, so that IP can and will change frequently. You *must* use a tool like `nslookup` or `dig` to get current results.

Comment: I used `nslookup irc.chat.twitch.tv` and tried all the ip addresses, but still no fix

Comment: I believe you need to call `htons` on the port number to convert it to network endianness.

Comment: @AndrewSun OMG, i tried one of the ip addresses from nslookup, used htons() and now it works! Ty! At the end it was that stupid mistake :)

Comment: regarding the statements: `#include "Authentication.h"` and 
`#include "MessageHandlers.h"`  The contents of those home grown header files are not posted, so we cannot reproduce the problem.  Please correct by posting the contents of those files

Comment: @user3629249 Those headers are not important since they just add the basic functionality of the chatbot, the problem was the missing `htons()` function.

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, stackoverflow requires that a [mcve] be posted.  Otherwise, the question is 'off topic'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved in comments above. The port number in `struct sockaddr_in` is in network endianness (aka big endian), while your computer is likely running as little endian. To assign it, you must use

```
addr.sin_port = htons(6667);
```

instead of

```
addr.sin_port = 6667;
```